# How to delete any number of "|" character at the end of the line REGEX?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 15k+ lines like this:

```
one|two|three|||||||||||||||
one|two|||||
one|two|three|four|five|six||||||||||
```

How would I delete all the pipes at the end of each line with REGEX? This will be done in Notepad++

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\|*$`

The pipe "|" symbol in a regex needs to be "escaped" with the "\"

also the "$" is used to indicate a line end.

The regex above escapes the pipe `\|` and repeats it for any number of times `*` until the line ends `$`

Answer (score 1):

Open the replace dialog and switch the "Search Mode" to "[Regular Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSMMl.gif)".   Enter  **[\|]+$**  under "Find what" and leave "Replace with" empty.   That's it.

Regards
Uwe